# Bitnami Gitlab+Redmine Auto Updating Repository Fails

Tags: git, ubuntu, redmine, gitlab, bitnami

I have searched around for solutions to this and tried various things however due to (from what i can gather) this being the less tred path, i have found nothing that works.

I have installed gitlab and redmine using a Bitnami native install on ubuntu 12.04 server. It is pretty much just a self contained installation of everything needed for these web services. I chose this route as I had little success installing these services on their own for a bit and I got sick of leaving mess around my system so this fixed that for me quite nicely.

I have set up redmine to be able to view a git "mirror" repository which is cloned from the gitlab service. It's a little annoying that i have to manually clone the repository as a mirror for each project but that is unrelated, it works. I have been using cron to auto update the repository from the main repository on gitlab every so often. However I wanted to instead make this event driven and make redmine update the repo when the gitlab repo updates.

This is where my problem begins. Not a lot of information of Gitlab+Redmine and pretty much none on using the two of them via Bitnami native installs. So I have installed the redmine plugin [redmine_gitlab_hook](https://github.com/phlegx/redmine_gitlab_hook) and it installed fine however the hook fails and the repository never updates in redmine.

By monitoring the redmine log file i have discovered that when the hook executes it spews a bunch of info on the hook parameters and this:

```
GitLabHook: Command '/usr/bin/git --git-dir='/var/repositories/nekroze/ninja.git' fetch --all' didn't exit properly. Full output: ["error: cannot open /var/repositories/nekroze/ninja.git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied\n", "\n"]
```

So, it needs to open that FETCH_HEAD file but doesn't have permissions. I have tried to add the relevant users to the git group, added /var/repositories to be owned by the git group, etc. I have tried changing everything but I cant get it to work it just says the same thing.

I believe that part of my problem may stem from the fact that I don't really know the user that redmine actually runs under as there is no redmine user as I have used bitnami so some things are a bit different.

Can anyone help me out here. I feel like I have come so far but I just can't get over this last hurdle and need a little assistance.

EDIT#1: For extra points, is it possible to use gitlab's wiki git repo that is automatically made for each project in redmine. I saw that there is a redmine plugin to use gollum for the wiki and I know that github uses that so maybe its possible?

Thanks for your time,
    Taylor "Nekroze" Lawson.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same issue right now